# Reading multiple return values from goroutines

Tags: function, go, concurrency, return-value

I'm trying to write wc(1) in Go, and I'm experimenting with goroutines in an effort to count large number of input files more efficiently. My code works fine as it is, but I have a hard time implementing a method to summarize the statistics for all the go routines. How can I pass the function variables `nl`, `nw`, `nc` to main and summarize them there once all the go routines have completed their work?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan string)

    for _, arg := range os.Args[1:] {
        go wc(arg, ch)
    }
    for range os.Args[1:] {
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
    }
    // Todo: summarize results...
}

func wc(arg string, ch chan<- string) {
    nl, nw, nc := 0, 0, 0

    file, err := os.Open(arg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Can't open file: %v", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scan := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scan.Scan() {
        nl++

        line := scan.Text()
        words := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(line))
        words.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
        for words.Scan() {
            nw++
        }

        runes := bufio.NewReader(strings.NewReader(line))
        for {
            if _, _, err := runes.ReadRune(); err != nil {
                break
            } else {
                nc++
            }
        }
    }

    ch <- fmt.Sprintf("%8d%8d%8d", nl, nw, nc+nl)
}
```

Comment: Please note that Go has goroutines, it does not have "go routines". The latter can be confusing for the reader because the term "routine" has certain meaning in computing.

Comment: I notice that even with defer file.Close(), this program will sometimes (seemingly randomly) fail with "too many files open". Should this be handled another way, by doing file opening/closing in Main, or by forcing file.Close() rather then defer in this case..?

Comment: «…fail with "too many files open"…»–changing the approach won't probably win you much. Because you hit this limit when the number of files opened _at the same time_ (see [`setrlimit(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/2/setrlimit#RLIMIT_NOFILE)) hits the limit (which you can check by running `ulimit -n` in your shell). One obvious improvement would be to close the file as soon as you have finished reading from it because in theory sending the results over the channel may take long time for whatever reason, and the file is still open during that time…

Comment: Note that you have a glaring problem with your code: you do not check (and communicate) errors which might occur during reading of a file. Expanding on the provided answers, you should augment your `struct` UDT which represents a single count result with a filed of type `error`, and check the `Err()` method of the scanner once `Scan()` method has returned `false`; if there's a non-nil error, you should send _it_ (and maybe the number of counted values to that moment) as a result, and process it "on the receiving side".

Comment: …at the same time, having that call defer-red is a good practice you should stick to, so you might want to refactor wc into two functions: one opens an *os.File, defers its closure, runs the "read+count" function then just returns the counts, and another one, which calls the 1st and then sends the results over the channel. This way, the file will remain open only for the period required to reading all its data.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive input :) Yeah, I'm purposely avoiding some error checking here in the alpha-stage so to speak, until I get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close to the answer! I suggest a quick refacto though to return a `Result` object with the numbers, that will allow to easily add them at the end (instead of using strings). So you can use a `chan Result` instead of `chan string`.

Basically, you can introduce a `totalResult` variable, and when iterating on all results, just add the results for `nl`, `nc` and `nw` into that total variable.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

// define a struct to hold the result
type Result struct {
    nl int
    nw int
    nc int
}

// this is to be able to use fmt.Println(result)
func (r Result) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%8d%8d%8d", r.nl, r.nw, r.nc+r.nl)
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan Result)

    for _, arg := range os.Args[1:] {
        go wc(arg, ch)
    }

    totalResult := Result{}

    for range os.Args[1:] {
        result := <-ch
        fmt.Println(result) // just for debugging

        // sum everything
        totalResult.nl += result.nl
        totalResult.nw += result.nw
        totalResult.nc += result.nc
    }

    fmt.Println("Total result:")
    fmt.Println(totalResult)
}

func wc(arg string, ch chan<- Result) {
    nl, nw, nc := 0, 0, 0

    // your logic to compute nl, nw, nc goes here

    ch <- Result{nl: nl, nw: nw, nc: nc + nl}
}
```

You should get something like this (with 3 files):

```
      37      50    4753
      19     106     821
      47     255    3806
Total result:
     103     411    9380
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is dead-simple and is not specific to Go or goroutines: when you need to pass multple values as a single unit, use a [compound data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_data_type).

In the case of Go, and in your particular case, the simplest is to declare a `struct` type and make your channel transfer values of this type.
The type could look like this:

```golang
type wcResult struct {
  nl int
  nw int
  nc int
}

ch := make(chan wcResult)
```